# Django annotate by adding months to date field

Tags: django, django-annotate

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import DateTimeField, ExpressionWrapper, F


MyModel.objects.annotate(
    date_plus345=ExpressionWrapper(F('creation_date') + timedelta(days=345),
        output_field=DateTimeField()
    )
)
```

Like this is there any ways to add 40 months to the creation_date field and annotate it?

Comment: Why not make it a poperty of your `MyModel` class?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Because I need to sort my result based on that field? So if I make it a property of model MyModel to sort I have to bring all the dataset from the database to the server, right?

Comment: but if this is each time 40 months, this means it is completely equivalent to filter on the `creation_date`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem months can be change based on some conditions. It will be a dynamically calculated value

Answer (score 0):

Does reative delata helps you?

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
    MyModel.objects.annotate(
        date_plus345=ExpressionWrapper(F('creation_date') + relativedelata(months+=40),
            output_field=DateTimeField()
        )
    )
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Raises `ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'relativedelta'`